# Datepicker not working on react router childs (until refresh)

Tags: jquery-ui, reactjs, datepicker, react-router, semantic-ui

I am facing a issue with the react router, where the child router has a component form with datepicker([semantic-ui-calender](https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar)) and a default dropdown from semantic-ui.

Issue is : By entering to the child route these styles are not working, shows only default select option for dropdown and datepicker was just a input now. If i refresh the page those are working.

Here is the router section

```
<Route path="/examination" component={Examination}>
        <IndexRoute component={Add_new_schedule}/>
        <Route path="/examination/AddNewSchedule" component={Add_new_schedule} />
        <Route path="/examination/AddExam" component={Add_exam} />
</Route>
```

Here is the Dropdown

```
<div className="exam_class_section">
              <select className="ui dropdown">
                <option value>Section</option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
              </select>
</div>
```

Here is the Datepicker (Semantic-UI-Calender) with date, time-from, time-to

```
<div className="exam_date_time_box">
            <div id="exam_date" className="ui calendar">
              <div className="ui left icon input">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Examination Date" />
                <i className="calendar icon" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="exam_time_box">
              <div id="time_from" className="ui calendar">
                <div className="ui input left icon">
                  <i className="time icon" />
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Time From" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="time_to" className="ui calendar">
                <div className="ui input left icon">
                  <i className="time icon" />
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Time To" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this problem.

The issue is because external js files will not load in **react-router**.

The Solution is load the external js file with **loadjs** library by importing into the specific component page where it is required

`import loadjs from 'loadjs'` and call inside **componentWillMound()** lifecycle method

```
componentWillMount() {
loadjs('/js/main.js');
},
```